# How can I recognize if window is being drawn on a touchable screen?

Tags: windows, winapi, touch

I would like to have two different layouts for my app: one for regular desktop and one for a touchable device.

How can I query if screen my app is being drawn on supports multitouch?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no direct way to query for input capabilities based on the display(s) a window is displayed on. You can, however, query the system for touch input capabilities.

On Windows XP and Windows Vista you can ask the system, whether a touch digitizer is attached to the system. It doesn't report, whether is supports multi-touch, though. The API to use is [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385.aspx):

```
bool TouchInputAvailable() {
    return ( ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_TABLETPC ) != 0 );
}
```

For systems running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 (and above), the OS reports multi-touch capabilities as well:

```
bool MultiTouchAvailable() {
    int value = ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_DIGITIZER );
    return ( ( value & ( NID_MULTI_INPUT | NID_READY ) )
                    == ( NID_MULTI_INPUT | NID_READY ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [`IsTouchWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372998(v=vs.85).aspx), which is defined through Winuser.h.

Comment: That API doesn't do, what the question is asking for. It returns `true` for any window on **any** display, that has been registered for touch input with a call to [RegisterTouchWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317326.aspx). A window can be registered to receive touch input, regardless of whether touch digitizer hardware is present, and windows aren't automatically registered to receive touch input, in case a digitizer is present.